# ¿Como dar formato entendible o identacion a un archivo css y/o js?

Tags: sublimetext3, atom-editor, sublimetext, phpstorm

No se si pertenezca, pero si alguien me puede ayudar le agradecería mucho.

Estoy tratando de editar unos codigos `css` y `javascript`, pero cuando abro estos archivos estos no tienen un formato entendible.

Esto me muestra en **phpStorm**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de similar forma los **js**(Me los muestra en solo una linea):

```
$(document).ready(function(){"use strict";var e=$("body");$(function(){$(".preloader").fadeOut(),$("#side-menu").metisMenu()}),$(".open-close").on("click",function(){e.toggleClass("show-sidebar").toggleClass("hide-sidebar"),$(".sidebar-head .open-close i").toggleClass("ti-menu")}),$(function(){var i=function(){var i=60,s=window.innerWidth>0?window.innerWidth:this.screen.width,l=(window.innerHeight>0?window.innerHeight:this.screen.height)-1;s<768?($("div.navbar-collapse").addClass("collapse"),i=100):$("div.navbar-collapse").removeClass("collapse"),s<1170?(e.addClass("content-wrapper"),$(".sidebar-nav, .slimScrollDiv").css("overflow-x","visible").parent().css("overflow","visible")):e.removeClass("content-wrapper"),l-=i,l<1&&(l=1),l>i&&$("#page-wrapper").css("min-height",l+"px")},s=window.location,l=$("ul.nav a").filter(function(){return this.href===s||0===s.href.indexOf(this.href)}).addClass("active").parent().parent().addClass("in").parent();l.is("li")&&l.addClass("active"),$(window).ready(i),$(window).bind("resize",i)}),$(".list-task li label").on("click",function(){$(this).toggleClass("task-done")}),$(".settings_box a").on("click",function(){$("ul.theme_color").toggleClass("theme_block")}),$(".collapseble").on("click",function(){$(".collapseblebox").fadeToggle(350)}),$(".slimscrollright").slimScroll({height:"100%",position:"right",size:"5px",color:"#dcdcdc"}),$(".slimscrollsidebar").slimScroll({height:"100%",position:"right",size:"6px",color:"rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"}),$(".chat-list").slimScroll({height:"100%",position:"right",size:"0px",color:"#dcdcdc"}),e.trigger("resize"),$(".visited li a").on("click",function(e){$(".visited li").removeClass("active");var i=$(this).parent();i.hasClass("active")||i.addClass("active"),e.preventDefault()}),$("#to-recover").on("click",function(){$("#loginform").slideUp(),$("#recoverform").fadeIn()}),$(".navbar-toggle").on("click",function(){$(".navbar-toggle i").toggleClass("ti-menu").addClass("ti-close")})});
```

De similar forma pasa en **sublimeText** y **atom**

Si alguien supiera como dar un formato entendible(**identación**), o que libreria tengo que utilizar se los agradeceria.

Comment: Por lo que veo los archivos estan minificados. En este caso puedes hacer el reverso de esto. Acá te dejo enlace de un paquete de sublime para unminifi. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS%20Unminifier. Pruebalo a ver que tal te va. tambien puedes probar con esta página. http://unminify.com/

Comment: Aunque ya respondieron correctamente, dejo por aquí mi pequeña aportación. Si solo quiero visualizar el código de forma rápida, no tengo un editor a mano, o no me se el atajo del que tengo instalado, uso estas webs que te lo identa al momento: Javascript: - [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/) CSS: - [cleancss.com](https://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una combinación de teclas para esta acción, pero depende de su esquema de asignación de teclas actual. Por ejemplo:

Elija el código para reformatear y presione:

**Para Windows:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (phpstorm)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (phpstorm)

**Para Mac:**

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Además puedes cambiar las combinaciones de teclas a tu gusto, pero se hace de forma diferente en cada editor

Comment: Me funciono perfecto el cuarto comando para wimdows

Comment: @Shassain  genial me alegra.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el plugin de Sublime Text **HTML-CSS-JS Prettify**

Lo haces del siguiente modo:

1. Presiona CTRL + Shift + P
2. Escribe prettify
3. Descarga cuando encuentres el que se llama HTML-CSS-JS Prettify

**MODO DE USO**

Selecciona todo el texto y presiona la combinación de teclas

Ctrl + Shift + H

Fuente original

[Mejorar código en sublime text](http://tonalidad.es/blog-de-notas/tutoriales/indentar-html-css-javascript-sublimetext/)

Comment: Lo intente, pero el paso dos es escribir **install package**, ademas despues de instalarlo me pidio tener nodejs y me aparece un codigo : `"node_path":
    {
        "windows": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe",
        "linux": "/usr/bin/nodejs",
        "osx": "/usr/local/bin/node"
    },`

Comment: te paso el gihub oficial de paquete para indicaciones mejor detalladas espero te sirva https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify