# Proteger mi codigo en php, laravel, javascript y css

Tags: php, javascript, sublimetext3

Hace un tiempo atras realize esta pregunta: [¿Como dar formato entendible o identacion a un archivo css y/o js?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154602/como-dar-formato-entendible-o-identacion-a-un-archivo-css-y-o-js)
, ahora lo que busco es el proceso inverso de eso.

es decir: teniendo cierto codigo:

```
   $("#btn_load").click(function(e){
      $.ajax({
          url:'{{url("liquidation/cod_unicotwo")}}',
          type:"GET",
          data:{fechai:$("#fecha_inicial").val(), fechaf: $("#fecha_final").val()},
          beforeSend: function(){
              $("#aquitabla").html($("#cargador_reporte").html());
          },
          success:function(data){
              info_print=ModeloTableSmall(data);
              $("#aquitabla").fadeIn(2000).html(info_print);
          }
      });
    });
```

Este se muestre en una sola linea:

```
$("#btn_load").click(function(e){$.ajax({url("liquidation/cod_unicotwo")}}',type:"GET",data:{fechai:$("#fecha_inicial").val(), fechaf: $("#fecha_final").val()},beforeSend: function(){$("#aquitabla").html($("#cargador_reporte").html());},success:function(data){info_print=ModeloTableSmall(data);$("#aquitabla").fadeIn(2000).html(info_print);}});});
```

Todo esto con el fin te proteger (por lo menos algo) el código.

Estoy trabajando con SublimeText3 y atom.

**EDICION**

Como el proceso inverso es simple de realizar, como podria proteger mi codigo? hay alguna forma de encriptarlo?

Comment: ¿Has probado http://dean.edwards.name/packer/ ? El proceso que deseas hacer se llama ofuscación.

Comment: hay muchos plugins para hacer esto con atom como minify, uglify, etc

Comment: También puedes usar webs como esta https://www.minifier.org . Esto no protege el código, normalmente se realiza para la optimización, lo hace ilegible, pero cualquiera puede hacerlo a la inversa. Saludos

Comment: buscare los plugins que @Emeeus indica.

Comment: El PHP no sale del servidor, no es necesario ofuscarlo.

Comment: Yo suelo usar esta web https://obfuscator.io/ para el tema de la ofuscación de JS y jQuery. Tira bastante bien, pero debes estar fino a la hora de las rutas. Leete el tutorial, porque es algo lioso, y nos dices.

Answer (score 1):

La minimización del código es un buen comienzo.

Puedes intentarlo con minimización, pero un programador lo suficientemente habilidoso debería ser capaz de dedicar cierta cantidad de tiempo para comprenderlo. El desarrollador de CKFinder (https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/ckfinder/) piensa tener bastante bien protegido su código, de hecho utiliza cadenas de texto transformadas para realizar llamadas a funciones y acceder a propiedades. Aún así en una semana conseguí configurarlo para usarlo de forma gratuita. No llegué a utilizarlo porque para mí solo era un reto, pero pretender proteger el código con tan solo minimización y transformación de texto no es del todo eficaz.

En mi experiencia, realizar un proceso de ingeniería inversa sobre código Javascript suele ser relativamente sencillo porque los mecanismos de ofuscación suelen mantener gran parte de la modularidad del código original.

**Lo que realmente sería problemático sería el empobrecer esa modularidad**.

Supón que hay una función especialmente importante en tu código javascript. Si solo lo minimizas, es muy sencillo (aunque tedioso) analizar la jerarquía de llamadas a funciones y deducir que esa función probablemente sea importante.

Sin embargo, ¿qué ocurriría si esa función se eliminara y se sustituyera por tres (por ejemplo) funciones equivalentes pero no iguales? Pues que has roto la jerarquía de llamadas, has empobrecido la calidad del código rompiendo parte de  su modularidad y ... has hecho bastante menos legible esa parte del código. La aplicación sistemática de esta técnica debería ser capaz de crear un auténtico quebradero de cabeza, el problema es que no conozco ningún transpilador de código que haga esto. Solo sé que es posible hacerlo de forma automática con los algoritmos de análisis y generación de código de teoría de compiladores.

Si realmente esta herramienta no existe sería más que interesante desarrollarla.

Answer (score 1):

1. La ofuscación de código no lo protegerá.
2. Al código php no podrán acceder si traran de buscar en el código fuente de tu html, eso ya sería un tema de seguridad del servidor.
3. En Sublime text puedes selecciónar el codigo y ofuscarlo automaticamente para ello puedes utilizar la combinación de teclas "Ctrl + A" y después "Ctrl + J"

Answer (score 1):

La minimización de código sólo vale para librerías `javascript`, y no precisamente para proteger código, sino para dificultar la lectura de forma muy pobre, ya que yo podría coger un código `min.js` y ponerlo con sus tabuladores, retornos de carro, etc.
Lo que protege un código fuente es la *OFUSCACIÓN*, que significa que dicho código fuente es sustituido por un texto ilegible con un par de funciones y librerías, unos *serials*, etc. `Sourcecop` hace esto. Alguien me dijo que un programador lo suficientemente bueno podría interpretar ese código (será verdad, pero yo he visto una ofuscación de `sourcecop` y no entendía ni papa).

También están otros como `Zend` (creo) que pasan el código a *BINARIO*, y ahí sí que no hay tutía. Eso no hay quien lo lea (al editarlo salen "marcianitos"). Como un código objeto.

Comment: No creo que la minimización de código sea para dificultar la lectura, si no mas bien para ahorrar pesos y cargas al servidor. Corrígeme si me equivoco, vaya, pero no tiene sentido que sea para dificultar lectura si cualquier editor de texto plano tiene un pretty js o pretty css.